# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip, pickle

I wrote this code to load a dataset into a data frame. Dataset is given in a pickle file but it throws an error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes'**

```
import pickle
import pandas
dbfile = open(dataset loction,'rb')
df = pickle.load(dbfile)
```

I tried all the fixes given:

1. Updated the pandas
2. used `df = pandas.read_picle(dataset location)`

Tried installing pickle using pip but getting this error

```
C:\installs\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64>python -m pip install pickle
Collecting pickle
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pickle
```

Comment: Please provide error details of the code. since its confusing with the title.

Comment: This is the complete error i am getting :`ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2a34c4ce9aec> in <module>()
      2 import pandas
      3 dbfile = open(r'C:\Users\raman\Downloads\df_train_api.pk','rb')
----> 4 df = pickle.load(dbfile)
      5 
      6 df

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes'`

Comment: We need to see the real implementation because the line dbfile = open(dataset loction,'rb') makes no sense and we can't tell if that's the source of error or if it's properly implemented

Comment: I have a dataset named **df_train_api.pk** that is stored in my downloads folder, I am using this specific code:      `import pickle
import pandas
dbfile = open(r'C:\Users\raman\Downloads\df_train_api.pk','rb')
df = pickle.load(dbfile)

df`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That smells like the pickle file has been created with a different version of Pandas, and your currently installed Pandas doesn't have the `pandas.core.indexes` module that some of the data in the pickle requires.

Which version of Pandas are you using? Have you tried upgrading?

EDIT: Pandas 0.19.2 does not have that module:

```
$ pip install pandas==0.23.3
$ python
>>> import pandas.core.indexes as i
>>>
$ pip install pandas==0.19.2
$ python
>>> import pandas.core.indexes as i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes'
>>>
```

Comment: I am using pandas version : **'0.19.2'**, yes I tried upgrading it.

Comment: @RAMANBHATIA Well, upgrading to 0.23.3 will have fixed your problem, I'm sure. See my edit...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using pandas pickle method to read .pk file.

```
import _pickle as cPickle
with open('filename.pkl', 'rb') as fo:
        dict = cPickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1’)
```

see doc here. [Pickle Read](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html)

Comment: I tried using this code `pandas.read_pickle(r'C:\Users\raman\Downloads\df_train_api.pk')` it also throws the same **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes'**

Comment: from which version of python your .pk file is created? also need to know your encoding method.

Comment: I don't have an idea about that, will it matter I am using python3.6 as of now. This is a part of interview assignment I got to complete.

Comment: it does matter if your pickle file is created with lower python version. like 2.7

Comment: Any fix for that matter as I am not sure if I can contact them now I have a deadline for tomorrow.

Comment: can't suggest without knowing pickle file meta data.
try from above answer code just updated. this is lower C level implementation of pickle.

Comment: also if you can locate this file in python installation that would be great to know about missing module.
under python installation site-package/pandas/core
index.py

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @AKX made me realise that it was probably a version problem Pandas. However, I only needed to upgrade.

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```