# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric' using Metaflow

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, netflix-metaflow

I used Metaflow to load a Dataframe. It was successfully unpickled from the artifact store, but when I try to view its index using `df.index`, I get an error that says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'`. Why?

I've looked at other answers with similar error messages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285798) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371451), which say that this is caused by trying to unpickle a dataframe with older versions of Pandas. However, my error is slightly different, and it is not fixed by upgrading Pandas (`pip install pandas -U`).

Comment: "However, my error is slightly different" - your error is **completely unrelated**, as you are not trying to use `pickle` at all (and you would see it in the stack trace if Metaflow were doing so). That problem is a general issue with pickling that, in turn, has really nothing to do with Pandas.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Incorrect-- Metaflow artifact tracking works using `pickle` The dataframe was unpickled from the metaflow artifact store, which worked successfully, and then I tried to run a simple `df.index` operation.

Comment: SO has a problem with hit-and-run Close votes based on incorrect assumptions, when clarification would've been more appropriate.

Comment: I did not VTC based on some incorrect assumption. In particular, I did not VTC because of thinking the problem was unrelated to Pickle (although I did think that). I did VTC because I personally feel that Stack Overflow should not host bug reports. However, [consensus is firmly against me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404646) so I have undone that and attempted to improve the question as much as possible.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This issue is caused by the new [Pandas 2.0.0 release](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html) breaking backwards compatibility with Pandas 1.x, although I don't see this documented in the release notes. The solution is to downgrade pandas to the 1.x series: `pip install "pandas<2.0.0"`

Comment: "although I don't see this documented in the release notes." That's because it wasn't supposed to be used in the first place. See the top level of [API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html) documentation: "The pandas.core, pandas.compat, and pandas.util top-level modules are PRIVATE. Stable functionality in such modules is not guaranteed." You should report this as a bug against metaflow.

Comment: (A pickled Dataframe, of course, is quite likely to contain references to such private/internal Pandas modules, because they were likely used in creating the Dataframe.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I never claimed that this is a bug against Pandas. I am simply reporting a solution to a cryptic error I encountered while doing a basic df operation. This isn't even a bug against Metaflow, either, unless Pandas happens to push out a major release (happened this week for the first time in 3 years).

Comment: I initially inferred that it was a bug against Metaflow because they should not have written code using that package, at all, for any reason. However, since they are wrapping the pickling process, they presumably don't really have a choice. More to the point: pickled Dataframes should be treated as **incompatible by default** across **any** two different versions of Pandas. This is in the nature of Pickle: it necessarily reaches into undocumented and private APIs, which library maintainers hold themselves free to break at any time (as is perfectly expected under semver).

Comment: Hi all, — to this day, pickle remains the best way ( and I think, only way, in the most general cases? ) to enure that savin andrestoring a DataFrame to disk is the identity map. Yes, everyone knows that pickles will break (by design and definition) across versions (and an update to ANYTHING a data frame touches can cause this). Many libraries opt for this fragile pickle solution because alternatives are somehow worse.

Comment: What do I mean by worse? Well, `.json`  and `.hdf5` were the most flexible options, last I checked, but even these would run into trouble if you were doing anything slightly fancy. For example, hierarchical rows or columns, or storing anything other than a simple primitive type, or mixing types in a weird way within a column, etc.

Comment: And then you need to decide: do I enforce these restrictions at all times, or only when I'm about to serialize to disk? If its at all times, have you wrapped your DataFrame (in classic OOP style) so that all actions a user *can* take enforce the required invariants? Or, if its just when serializing: Have you written clear error messages and provided adequate helper routines to guide a user who is surprised when they suddenly can't save their data? Or, if you silently try to coerce the dataframe into e.g. a HDF5-safe format, will users encounter data loss or unwelcome surprises?

Comment: Probably the "correct" way to do this is to extend DataFrame into various classes like HDF5SafeDataFrame, JSONSafeDataFrame, etc., but this may require quite a bit of extra legwork if you want these derived classes to interoperate correctly with third-party code that expects a vanilla DataFrame? So yeah. I think there is a pretty strong argument that, in some cases, Pickle *is* the correct design choice. It has drawbacks, but sometimes the alternatives are just worse.

Answer (score 36):

Try using the [`pandas.read_pickle()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html) method to load the file instead of the `pickle` module:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_pickle("file.pkl")
```

The pandas method should provide compatibility to read older files, and "is only guaranteed to be backwards compatible to pandas 0.20.3 provided the object was serialized with to_pickle." My tests with pandas-1.x show it can also read some files written from the `pickle` module too.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `pd.compat.pickle_compat.load()` as that was only solution in my case:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.compat.pickle_compat.load('file.pkl')
```

Comment: ^^^ this should be the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

So i dont know why this works but joblib.load was failing to read the pickle with the same error "module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'" then i installed prefect and simple_salesforce and some how it now works... not sure why but i think worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

try this if you using pandas > 2.0.0

Import necessary libraries:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
```

Get the absolute path to the current directory:

```py
current_directory = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

Construct the absolute path to the pickle file ('file.pkl' in this case):

```py
file_path_file = os.path.join(current_directory, 'file.pkl')
```

Use pandas to read the pickle file directly:

```py
file_df = pd.read_pickle(file_path_file)
```