# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'

Tags: python, flask, pickle

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
import pickle
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

with open('C:\\Users\\captain\\Desktop\\flask\\my-project\\movies.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    Movies = pickle.load(f)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

The code shown above is giving this error (shown in image) when I run "flask --app main run" this statement :

[image]

But while running the main.py in the console it runs perfectly and I was able to print the Movies data using the print statement.

the data type of Movies =  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

I was just expecting that the Flask app would run fine without any errors.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/75953280/4212158

Answer (score 2):

This issue is similar with this thread, although you have it with pickle rather than metaflow

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric' using Metaflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953279/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-core-indexes-numeric-using-metaflo)

And the solution is the same:

```
pip install "pandas<2.0.0"
```

Tested on my computer (Ubuntu 22.04, Python 3.10.6) and pickle works again.